# Add space within a line

Tags: shell

I have many files named a, b, c and so on. These files contain line like this:-

```
11.077-105.882
-22.134-302.321
-1.011-201.254
```

I want to add a space when - sign come in mid of line. I want my output file look like this:-

```
11.077 -105.882
-22.134 -302.321
-1.011 -201.254
```

I have tried this command:-

```
cat a |sed 's/-/ -/g' >out.txt
```

But it do not give desired result

Answer (score 1):

Require (and capture) a character before each `-` to replace:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)-/\1 -/g' < tmp.txt
11.077 -105.882
-22.134 -302.321
-1.011 -201.254
```

This will only match a `-` that is not line-initial, and will include the preceding character in the replacement text.

Comment: Are there any implementations of `sed` that do not treat the last parameter as the filename?

Comment: Probably not; that was just an automatic response to getting rid of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine 2 `sed` commands:

```
$ sed 's/-/ -/g' a | sed 's/^ //'
11.077 -105.882
-22.134 -302.321
-1.011 -201.254
```

Or, in a single line solution add whitespaces only before `-` that come after a digit:

```
$ sed 's,\([0-9]\)-,\1 -,' a
11.077 -105.882
-22.134 -302.321
-1.011 -201.254
```